# Is there any way to host Bugzilla over a cloud?

Tags: testing, bugzilla, manual-testing

Any one know, is it possible to host Bugzilla application in cloud ?

Comment: And what does "in cloud" mean?

Comment: Currently we hosted Bugzilla in our office local server,because of this, access permission only from our office network.If it possible to host in Cloud our developers can log-in through online and they can work from any where.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I *guess* with "in cloud" you mean at a hosting provider on something like a virtual server. Certainly that is possible. Bugzilla is a server side application that relies on a http server and an smtp server for communication and a relational database in background, all not a problem here. However bugzilla is, unlike typical web applications, implemented mostly in `perl` (language). That means you have to find a hosting provider offering such environment. That is possible from a technical point of view, but not very common. This is also explained in the documentation.

Comment: Thank you for the information... I have one more doubt in bugzilla. I am using Bugzilla 3.6.3

All functionality are working fine, except mail authentication.Once I create one new bug and submit, application not allowing to send any mail to respective assigner. Saying that couldn't authenticate registered e-mail id.

How to clear this issue, Please help me.

Comment: Please ask this as a separate question, this has nothing to do with the question at hand.